# Encuentro en Valencia el 14 de junio (actualizado: lugar y hora)

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

Stack Overflow en español no es una red social, no hay listas de amigos ni mensajes privados, pero todo en Stack Overflow en español lo hace la comunidad para la comunidad. Me parece que sería genial reunirse un día!

> ¡Tengamos un encuentro!

Planeo estar en la hermosa y soleada Alicante en la segunda semana de junio (del 10 de junio al 16 de junio) y me gustaría organizar un encuentro de la comunidad de Stack Overflow en español.

Estoy pensando en un tipo de evento muy simple pero más interesante desde mi punto de vista: reunirse en un bar o en un parque para conocernos, compartir ideas, pensamientos sobre la programación y sobre la comunidad, y simplemente hablar sobre lo que sea en un ambiente informal.

Hay algunas opciones para la fecha, hora y lugar. Aunque originalmente iré a Alicante, personalmente creo que si tenemos la reunión en Valencia, más personas podrán asistir. Si tienes intención de asistir, comparte tus preferencias de fecha, hora y lugar en este [Formulario de Google](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdvn1cU_WlJQlmlxrzFPbfiKNyBwSh2a-Y6gVJugOcvuQpv8g/viewform). Nos ayudará a elegir las opciones más convenientes para todos.

Por favor, ven a la reunión de la comunidad y pasa un tiempo con tus compañeros. ¡Me alegrará veros a todos!

Comment: I'm glad you are visiting Spain :) Sadly I won't be able to be there (Alicante is far from where I live), but I hope some members can assist.

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias! Espero conocerte algún día! =)

Comment: Since you will be close to Mallorca you could come and visit this beautiful island! Please ping me if you do :-)

Comment: Hola , me intersaria ir , hay alguna fecha ya decidida?

Comment: @AlvaroCC ¡Hola! Por favor mira la respuesta a continuación.

Comment: Una pena no poder asistir :'( A ver para cuando una en Zaragoza ;)

Comment: ¡Publiquen las fotos!

Comment: @fredyfx Por favor, mira la actualización de la respuesta.

Answer (score 7):

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

**Actualizar**. Vamos a encontrarnos en "[Foster's Hollywood](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/38.3472009,-0.4785588/Foster's+Hollywood+Plaza+del+Ayuntamiento,+Pla%C3%A7a+de+l'Ajuntament,+7,+46002+Val%C3%A8ncia/@38.9067968,-1.0061362,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!4m8!1m1!4e1!1m5!1m1!1s0xd604f4c813ba131:0x656b589e3ac8c4d5!2m2!1d-0.3768896!2d39.4717394)", Plaça de l'Ajuntament, 7, València. A las 18:00. Se debe reservar una mesa sobre "Nicolas". =)

---

De acuerdo a las respuestas en el Formulario de Google, el encuentro se producirá el viernes, 14 de Junio en Valencia. Empezaremos a las 18:00, pero si no puedes llegar a dicha hora es perfectamente aceptable unirse mas tarde.

Se agradecerían sugerencias en comentarios a esta respuesta cualquier lugar en Valencia donde podamos reunirnos un grupo pequeño y pasar un buen rato (probablemente un bar que no esté muy concurrido).

Es una reunión mas o menos informal. No se requiere corbata =) Todos sois bienvenidos incluso sin registro (aunque si te registras, te enviaré un correo electrónico con los detalles).

¡Estoy deseando veros a todos allí!

**Update** (I would appreciate the translation of the update.)

In the Russia language there is a phrase “We are few, but we are wearing singlets” (The Google’s version “The few, the proud”): a lot of thanks to David who came to the meetup! Three hours have passed as three minutes. We were talking about car nozzles, if one can win in a casino, and why C# is better than Java (sad but true) and many-many other things. It was a lot of fun!

A few photos of the event!

The venue in Valencia. A few hours before the meetup. The place is good for meetups. It is quiet, bright, few people, no loud music.

[image: The place of the event]

David and me at the end of the meetup!

[image: Hey! It was a lot of fun]

I brought a few stickers for everyone who would come.

[image: The stickers]

See you all next time!

P.S. Just in case, it was a joke about C# =)

Comment: _and why C# is better than Java (sad but true)_  that's a meeting I would go everytime :) It's a pity that more people couldn't assist, but i'm sure you had a fun time. I hope next time I could show up

Comment: Fué un verdadero placer haber tenido la oportunidad de haberte conocido, pasamos un rato muy agradable, hablando de todo :)